# How to convert tf.contrib to Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I'm trying to implement object detection using Tensorflow and a part of my code uses tf.contrib. The problem is tf.contrib is not supported in Tensorflow 2.0.

I've tried using the tf_upgrade_v2 script but I get the following message:

ERROR: Using member tf.contrib.slim in deprecated module tf.contrib. tf.contrib.slim cannot be converted automatically. tf.contrib will not be distributed with TensorFlow 2.0, please consider an alternative in non-contrib TensorFlow, a community-maintained repository such as tensorflow/addons, or fork the required code.

```py
import functools
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.core import box_predictor
from object_detection.utils import shape_utils
from object_detection.utils import static_shape

slim = tf.contrib.slim
```

Comment: As you already point out, TF-slim is not supported in 2.x (see e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25227)). If you want to upgrade your version of TensorFlow, you should probably consider rewriting your model in Keras.

Comment: I'm already using TensorFlow 2.0. Should I rewrite the entire model or just download an older version of Tensorflow?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to make the choice... If it is not much effort (i.e. if the model is a stack of standard layers) it may be worth rewriting the model, as Slim is rather dated now and not supported anymore. However, if you have a quirky model that is already working perfectly fine, you might find it is easier to just go back to an older version...

Comment: Did you get any solution for it? Please post it. I could not find anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the projects in `tf.contrib` were not officially supported by Tensorflow and it had designated owners for maintaining it.
 All the contributions and features were meant to merge into core Tensorflow.

From the Tensorflow 2.0 version all the contrib projects had one of three options for its future: `move to core`; `move to a separate repository`; or `delete`, most of which have been reviewed with the respective project owners.

This [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md) provides the details and status for all the projects under `tf.contrib`.

If the library you are using is moved to the core or separate repository, the TensorFlow's automatic code migration from 1.x to 2.x will not work for `tf.contrib` projects.  You need to change your code manually for these parts, which is suggested going forward.

I can see in the table that `tf.contrib.slim` is moved to `tensorflow/models` , you can follow this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim) for the usage in detail.

Comment: where is `tf.contrib.crf`?

Comment: got it. It is in `tensorflow_addons` module. https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `slim` and I solved it with [TensorFlow-Slim](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim). You have to install this library as `pip install --upgrade tf_slim` and then substitute `slim = tf.contrib.slim` in your code with `import tf_slim as slim`.

For other modules stored in `tf.contrib`, you have to find where they were moved in TF 2.x